# Perform code on multiple files 1 by 1 pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, glob

Hi I have code I have written to read a .csv file in a folder and add some required columns.
I now want to perform this code on multiple files within the path folder 1 by 1 and save each as a separate df.

My current code is as follows

```
    import pandas as pd
    import glob
    import os

    path = r'C:\Users\jake.jennings.BRONCO\Desktop\GPS Reports\Games\Inputs\2022-03-27 Vs 
    Cowboys\Test' # use your path
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

    li = []

    for filename in all_files:
        frame = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, skiprows=8)
        li.append(frame)

    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename

    #Add odometer change and turn all accel values to positive
    import numpy as np
    frame['OdChange'] = frame['Odometer'].diff()
    frame['accelpos'] = frame['Acceleration'].abs()

    #Add column with OdChange @ >5.5m/s
    frame["new1"] = np.where(
       (frame.Velocity >=5.5), 
       frame["OdChange"], 
       '0')

    #Add column with accels/decels >2.5m.s.s for AccelDec/min
    frame["new2"] = np.where(
       (frame.accelpos >=2.5), 
       frame["accelpos"], 
       '0')

    #Add column with accels/decels >2.5m.s.s for AccelDec/min
    frame["new3"] = np.where(
       (frame.Acceleration >=2.5), 
       '1', 
       '0')

    s = frame['new3'].astype(int)
    frame['new4'] = s.diff().fillna(s).eq(1).astype(int)
    frame['new4']

    #m/min peaks
    frame['1minOD'] = frame['OdChange'].rolling(window=600, axis=0).sum()
    #HSm/min peaks
    frame['1minHS'] = frame['new1'].rolling(window=600, axis=0).sum()
    #AccImpulse/min
    frame['1minImp'] = frame['accelpos'].rolling(window=600, axis=0).mean() *60
    #AccDec Peak Count
    frame['1minAccCount'] = frame['new4'].rolling(window=600, axis=0).sum()
    print (frame)
```

I am not sure if this is even the best way to do what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your Question?

Comment: How can I perform that process on multiple .csv files one by 1 in a folder and save each as a separate dataframe?

Comment: You mean rather than concatenating them all together?

Comment: Yes that is right